# Passing an array to a function that's been scanned

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm struggling with sending array data that's been previously scanned to a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int display(int a[21]);

int main(){
    int i;
    int a[21];
    FILE*fpointer;
    fpointer=fopen("data.txt","r");
    if (fpointer==NULL){
        printf("\nFile could not be found.");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        for (i=0;i<21;i++){
            fscanf(fpointer, "%d",&a[i]);   
        }
        fclose(fpointer);
    }
    display(int a[21]);
    return 0;
}

int display(int a[21]){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<21;i++){
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use the display() function to display each value from data.txt. I am able to fscanf every into the array, I just can't seem the send the array to the function.

data.txt:

```
1
6
4
7
3
4
12
14
15
-17
-19
21
-23
0
37
0
-31
32
34
-37
-39
```

Output values:

```
1065353216
1086324736
1082130432
1088421888
1077936128
1082130432
1094713344
1096810496
1097859072
-1048051712
-1047003136
1101529088
-1044905984
0
1108606976
0
-1040711680
1107296256
1107820544
-1038876672
-1038352384
```

Comment: Where you have `display(int a[21]); return 0;` at the end of `main()`, you have an improper declaration of `display()` (improper because there's no return type stated; OK in C90, sort of, but not in C99 or C11) and not a call to the function.  You need `display(a);` there.

Comment: You should also check that each `fscanf()` call succeeds (returns `1`).  If you get any other return value, there's a data problem.  It isn't clear why `display()` is defined to return an `int`.  It would be more sensible if it explicitly returned nothing (`void`).  And then you'd get warnings about conflicting declarations for the function `display()`.

Answer (score 4):

At the end of `main`, this is not a function call:

```
        …
    }
    display(int a[21]);
    return 0;
}
```

Because the type of the parameter is included, this is considered a *declaration* (without a return type, so implicitly `int`).  To call a function, just pass the required parameters:

```
display(a);
```

Comment: If i change to display(a); then I get in the display function, that a[i] subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector.

Comment: To be clear, he was telling you to change it to `display(a)` when you call the function, not where you define the function or the prototype.

Comment: @Christian You shall **only** change `display(int a[21]);` that is just above the `return 0;` The two other places shall be left as is. So `display(int a[21]);
    return 0;` --> `    display(a);
    return 0;
`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I have made these changes, but I get different values, for my integers, when a[0] should be 6, i get 1065353216. when a[9] should be -17, i get -1048051712.

Comment: @Christian How exactly is your data file laid out?  If the numbers are separated *only* by spaces and/or newlines, it should be printing out what was read.  If you have commas in the file, your format string isn't accounting for those.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons The data is only separated by newlines?

Comment: @Christian At this point, you may want to post a separate question with your updated code, a copy of your input file, and the expected and actual output.  If this answer solved your original problem, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int display(int a[21]);

int main(){
    int i;
    int a[21];
    FILE*fpointer;
    fpointer=fopen("data.txt","r");
    if (fpointer==NULL){
        printf("\nFile could not be found.");
        exit(1);}

    else{
        for (i=0;i<21;i++){
        fscanf(fpointer, "%d",&a[i]);}  

        fclose(fpointer);}
        display(a);
return 0;
}
int display(int a[21]){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<21;i++){
      printf("%d\n",a[i]);}
return 0;
}
```

Results are now displayed. I was scanning a %f rather than a %d, also the display(a) in the main function rather than display(int a[])